# How to import the facebook php sdk v4 in cakephp 2.4.?

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp, sdk

Trying to import and use the FacebookRedirectLoginHelper class of the facebook php sdk in my AppController but getting a Class 'FacebookRedirectLoginHelper' not found Exception.

```
App::import('Vendor', 'facebook', array('file' => 'facebook-php-sdk-v4-master' . DS . 'src' . DS . 'Facebook' . DS . 'FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php'));

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url, 'xxxx', 'yyyyy');
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem before and got it working now, not sure if I'm doing it in a proper way or not but it's working for me.

**1. Place this in your AppController (can be in function like beforeFilter or top of code)**

```
<?php App::import("Vendor", "FacebookAuto", array("file" => "facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php")); ?>
```

**2. Place as well the 'use' keyword in any Controller you want to call the facebook class**

```
<?php 
use Facebook\FacebookSession; 
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
?>
```

**3. You definitely have to do session_start() with FacebookRedirectLogin Helper**

**4. Start your FacebookSession and prepare your Redirect URL, and it will work nicely**

```
<?php
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication("APP_ID", "SECRET_ID");
$facebookRedirect = Router::url('/controllers/action', true);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($facebookRedirect);
?>
```

Hope it will solve your problem!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and tried most of the solutions here. In the end nothing worked because I was point to the wrong build and I was not telling CakePHP to use the Composer Autoloader.

In my composer.json I changed:
`"facebook/php-sdk-v4": "dev-master"` 
to 
`"facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*"`
and at the top of my `Config/bootstrap.php` file I added

```
<?php
// Load Composer autoload.
require APP . 'Vendor/autoload.php';

// Remove and re-prepend CakePHP's autoloader as Composer thinks it is the
// most important.
// See: http://goo.gl/kKVJO7
spl_autoload_unregister(array('App', 'load'));
spl_autoload_register(array('App', 'load'), true, true);
```

The proper composer entry was found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

The composer autoloder with CakePHP was found here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#installing-cakephp-with-composer

Now from anywhere in my app I can do this:

```
<?php
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('app_id', 'app_secret');
```

Hope it helps and that this issue does not deter you from continuing to use Composer.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem and it seems I can't solve it.
The work around for me is to use older version at:[FB SDK V3](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I have it working.

Below is the directory structure of the Vendor Dir ( My use-case is inside a plugin but all in all the same as if inside your apps Vendor Dir)

[image: Here's the directory structure of the Vendor Dir ( My use-case is inside a plugin but all in all the same as if inside your apps vendor dir)]

Then, I use a helper class ( not a CakePHP Helper, just a class that helps me out ;-) ) to include the SDK php files.

*NOTE: The order the SDK file are included is important to avoid race conditions in the class declarations.

You can then see how I request the login URL.

This is just a simple example of how I have it working.

Your milage may vary, however, should get your ball rollin

```
<?php

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;


class FacebookApiHelper {


public static $init = false;

public static function init() {

    if(!self::$init) {

        foreach(array(
                    'GraphObject.php',
                    'FacebookHttpable.php',
                    'FacebookCurlHttpClient.php',
                    'FacebookSDKException.php',
                    'FacebookRequestException.php',
                    'FacebookAuthorizationException.php',
                    'FacebookCanvasLoginHelper.php',
                    'FacebookClientException.php',
                    'FacebookCurl.php',
                    'FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper.php',
                    'FacebookOtherException.php',
                    'FacebookPageTabHelper.php',
                    'FacebookPermissionException.php',
                    'FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php',
                    'FacebookRequestException.php',
                    'FacebookRequest.php',
                    'FacebookResponse.php',
                    'FacebookServerException.php',
                    'FacebookSession.php',
                    'FacebookThrottleException.php',
                    'GraphAlbum.php',
                    'GraphLocation.php',
                    'GraphSessionInfo.php',
                    'GraphUser.php',
                    ) 
            as $file) {

            require_once __DIR__ . DS . "/Facebook/{$file}";
        }


        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(
            Configure::read("UserManager.FacebookApi.app_id"),
            Configure::read("UserManager.FacebookApi.app_secret")
        );

        self::$init = true;

    }

}

public static function getLoginUrl($callback_url = "/user_manager/login/handle_facebook_login_redirect") {

    self::init();

    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($callback_url);

    return $helper->getLoginUrl();

}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Hi, I couldn't get this problem solved with any of answerers you provided, but I managed to find my own solution with the help of my colleague.*

**Versions** I'm using here are: CakePHP 2.3, Facebook PHP SDK 4.0.0, PHP 5.4.

1. I downloaded Facebook SDK from developers.facebook.com.
2. I put
       src-folder files in cakephp app/Vendor/FacebookSDK/src.
3. In my controller-file called DashboardController I'm now including
   Facebook SDK like this:

   ```
   App::import('Vendor', 'FacebookRedirectLoginHelper', array('file' => 'FacebookSDK' . DS . 'src' . DS . 'FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php'));
   App::import('Vendor', 'FacebookSDKException', array('file' => 'FacebookSDK' . DS . 'src' . DS . 'FacebookSDKException.php'));
   App::import('Vendor', 'FacebookSession', array('file' => 'FacebookSDK' . DS . 'src' . DS . 'FacebookSession.php'));
   App::import('Vendor', 'FacebookRequest', ['file' => 'FacebookSDK' . DS . 'src' . DS . 'FacebookRequest.php']);
   App::import('Vendor', 'FacebookRequestException', ['file' => 'FacebookSDK' . DS . 'src' . DS . 'FacebookRequestException.php']);
   ```
4. And use it like this in my DashboardsController Facebook-method:

   ```
   $helper = new \Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(Router::url('/', true), $appId, $secret);
   ```

   Notice that \Facebook\ , that is the **namespace** of class FacebookRedirectLoginHelper. Without this namespace, code could find the file but not the class inside the file.